# Set variable before every controller

Tags: php, symfony

**Notice beforehand: I can't use the security bundle because the database I use is also used by other applications which are built on a whole other role system.**

I'm trying to set a variable to check if a user is logged in before each controller action. What I would like to do is check if it's logged in (by a session) and if that is the case load the entity corresponding to a query in my UserRepository.

I know this would normally be done via the Security Bundle of Symfony but since it requires you to implement the UserProviderInterface I can't use it at all, however if someone knows if you can write your own UserProviderInterface with a custom translation mapping for roles. That would be great too.

I hope I've been informative about my question.

**TL;DR:** Is there a way to set a variable before every controller action which can be accessed by the following controller.

Comment: why dont you use cookies?

Comment: @AslanKaya Because a cookie is insecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use sessions:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();

    // store an attribute for reuse during a later user request
    $session->set('foo', 'bar');

    // get the attribute set by another controller in another request
    $foobar = $session->get('foobar');

    // use a default value if the attribute doesn't exist
    $filters = $session->get('filters', array());
}
```

please check link http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html

Comment: Is it possible to set an entity into a session? Edit: Well it seems it is. For some reason I thought this was not possible! Thanks for the quick answer!